# Clojure Set vs Map Lookup Performance Differences

Tags: clojure

I have a list of uids and want to check if a uid is a member of this list

The natural way to implement it would be to create a set (`clojure.set`) of uids and search for that member on that list

What I found out is that map key lookup is a lot faster - I used the following snippet to benchmark both methods:

```clj
(def uids #{:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :a1 :b1 :c1 :d1 :e1 :f1 :h1 :i1 :j1 :k1 :l1 :m1 :n1 :o1 :p1})
(def uids-map (reduce (fn [acc v] (assoc acc v true)) {} uids))
(time (dotimes [i 1000000] (:o1 uids)))
;user=> "Elapsed time: 191.076266 msecs"
(time (dotimes [i 1000000] (:o1 uids-map)))
;user=> "Elapsed time: 38.159388 msecs"
```

the results were very consistent across invocations - map lookup took about 1/5 of set lookup

So is set not optimal for key lookup or am I using it the wrong way?

Also, what are the reasons for the differences in these benchmarks?

I was under the impression that a set is implemented in clojure as an associative data structure similar to vectors  - so why is key lookup significantly slower than a simple map?

Comment: Have you tried with `contains?` If you are only interested in the existence of a "key", that would be the appropiate function; you benchmark `get` here.  Also I'd use criterium for such "micro-benchmarks"

Comment: `contains?` seems to be faster, but still only about half as fast as a key lookup

Comment: I have with criterium: contains/map: 16, contains/set: 34, get/map: 15, get/set: 103

Comment: also, the difference is not order-of-magnitudes I would not spend too much time worrying about this and use the data structure that makes most sense. 
Measure first, optimize later.

Comment: i.e. chances are that in the actual usage of this code, you won't see much difference and that there are other, more fruitful, areas of optimization

Comment: Try to use the set as a function: `(uids :o1)` should be as fast as `(uids-map :o1)`.

Comment: @cgrand this seems to be right - can you explain why it works this way and add this as an answer?

Comment: @ErezRabih added an attempt to answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never went into clojure's source but from what I see the set implementation [actually uses a map inside](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentSet.java#L25):

```
protected APersistentSet(IPersistentMap impl){
    this.impl = impl;
}
```

It also delegates the [`invoke`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentSet.java#L49) call to the internal map.

In [APersistentSet](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentSet.java):

```
public Object invoke(Object arg1) {
    return get(arg1);
}

// ....

public Object get(Object key){
    return impl.valAt(key);
}
```

In [APersistentMap](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java):

```
public Object invoke(Object arg1) {
    return valAt(arg1);
}

public Object invoke(Object arg1, Object notFound) {
    return valAt(arg1, notFound);
}
```

So this can't explain the difference.

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911422/clojure-set-vs-map-lookup-performance-differences/58923321#comment104091623_58911422) by @cgrand, when we reverse the arguments its faster (and about the same, since we call set's `invoke` immediately). So I looked up [Keyword](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java)'s [`invoke`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java#L136) which is what is probably used for `(:k obj)`:

```
final public Object invoke(Object obj, Object notFound) {
    if(obj instanceof ILookup)
        return ((ILookup)obj).valAt(this,notFound);
    return RT.get(obj, this, notFound);
}
```

The important thing to notice is that [`ILookup`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ILookup.java) is implemented in `APersistentMap` (through [`Associative`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Associative.java#L12)) but not in `APersistentSet`. You can also verify in clojure:

```
(instance? clojure.lang.ILookup #{}) ;; false
(instance? clojure.lang.ILookup {})  ;; true
```

So maps go through the "happy path" and sets end up in [`RT.get`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L758) which I believe is the runtime.

Lets have a look at the runtime.

It Initially attempts to do practically the same thing as keyword:

```
static public Object get(Object coll, Object key){
    if(coll instanceof ILookup)
        return ((ILookup) coll).valAt(key);
    return getFrom(coll, key);
}
```

But since we know sets do not implement `ILookup` we know they go to [`RT.getFrom`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L764):

```
static Object getFrom(Object coll, Object key){
    if(coll == null)
        return null;
    else if(coll instanceof Map) {
        Map m = (Map) coll;
        return m.get(key);
    }
    else if(coll instanceof IPersistentSet) {
        IPersistentSet set = (IPersistentSet) coll;
        return set.get(key);
    }
    else if(key instanceof Number && (coll instanceof String || coll.getClass().isArray())) {
        int n = ((Number) key).intValue();
        if(n >= 0 && n < count(coll))
            return nth(coll, n);
        return null;
    }
    else if(coll instanceof ITransientSet) {
        ITransientSet set = (ITransientSet) coll;
        return set.get(key);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Which leads me to believe the main difference is the extra delegations and `instanceof` calls due to sets not implementing `ILookup`.

As bonus I've added a test on a set that implements `ILookup` and delegates `valAt` to the internal map immediately (using `proxy`) which closed the gap a bit:

```
(def uids #{:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i :j :k :l :m :n :o :p :a1 :b1 :c1 :d1 :e1 :f1 :h1 :i1 :j1 :k1 :l1 :m1 :n1 :o1 :p1})
(def uids-map (into {} (for [k uids] [k k])))
(def lookupable-set (proxy [clojure.lang.APersistentSet clojure.lang.ILookup] [uids-map]
                      (valAt [k] (get uids-map k))))

;; verify
(instance? clojure.lang.APersistentSet lookupable-set) ;; true
(instance? clojure.lang.ILookup lookupable-set) ;; true

(time (dotimes [i 1000000] (:o1 uids))) ;; 134.703101 msecs
(time (dotimes [i 1000000] (:o1 lookupable-set))) ;; 63.187353 msecs  <-- faster
(time (dotimes [i 1000000] (:o1 uids-map))) ;; 35.802762 msecs <-- still fastest
```

To conclude: Where performance matters - invoking the set `(#{...} k)` without going through keyword `(k #{...})` is as fast as map.

But I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `contains?` uses `clojure.lang.RT.contains` which has plenty of `instanceof` checks (compared to `containsKey`), which is likely the cause of the performance difference.